# VBA For Loop, Not Looping Through Spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Updated code based on recommended solution, still does not work.  Only loops through same worksheet.

Updated code now shown below.

I am pulling my hair out here!  I am trying to create a simple look, my first attempt ever, that will add rows to the top of my data, insert sum totals, resize the columns, and then move on to the next worksheet.  Everything works perfect, except when it comes to going to the next worksheet.

Depending on how I have the code written, it either recycles the same process into the same worksheet, or simply ends after completing the process on the current worksheet.  I've tried about ten different wants, and no matter what I do, it doesnt work.

The crazy thing is, I copy and past an identical code into a new module, and it works perfect!

I dont understand where I am going wrong.  Couple of things, the macro is saved in my personal workbook, but moving it to the current workbook doesnt fix the problem.  Also, the tabs of each worksheet have unique names, so something like, Company 1, company 2... and so on, for about ten companies.

Here is the code, please tell me I'm not crazy here!

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

' Loop Through Worksheets, Add Totals

Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim iIndex As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long

' = Loop Sum Formula Through All Worksheets

    For iIndex = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set WS = Worksheets(iIndex)
        With WS

        Rows("1:6").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

        Range("K7:Q7").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("K3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        LastRow = Range("A20000").End(xlUp).Row

        Range("K4").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sum(K8:K" & LastRow & ")"

        Range("K4:Q4").Select
        Selection.FillRight

        Range("K:Q").Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        Range("A1").Select

        End With

    Next iIndex


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the previously answered question.  I tried adjusting my code to match what was posted, but all it does is continue to loop the same " 'do something" in the same worksheet, and still does not select or loop through the remaining worksheets.  Updated code on original posting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add a `.` in front of the `Rows`, `Range`, `Cells`, etc. calls. Otherwise you're just modifying the current "active sheet". So the first line after the `With` statement would be `.Rows("1:6").Select`.

Comment: Gave that a shot.  The code is now recognizing the number of sheets I have in my workbook, but still repeating the same code on only the first worksheet.  So it knows there are nine total sheets, and continues to repeat the code nine times on the same worksheet.  With the dots (.) inserted after each call command, it gives me an error after completing the code one time.    

Tells me "Select method of Range class failed", when it hits ".rows("1:6").Select".

Some progress?

Comment: Try doing this: `Dim ws as Worksheet`, `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets`, `With ws`, `.Rows("1:6").Insert Shift:=xlDown`, `.Range("K3:Q3").Value = .Range("K7:Q7").Value`... and so on. Try to avoid using `Select` or `Activate` where you can.

Comment: Thanks J_Lard.  This still didn't make much of a difference.  I am going bonkers as to why my code will not cycle through each worksheet.  It doesn't make sense to me.   After it cycles through the "End With", "Next iIndex", it just goes to end sub.  Even when i try the For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets, With ws it just goes to <!--end sub -->

Comment: What type of code module is the code in, and is it in the same workbook as the sheets you want to loop over?

Comment: It is not, it is in a module within my personal macro library.  I attempted to copy the macro to the workbook itself, but still no change.  I'm at a loss here.  This should be simple, i'm sure of it, but this just wont work!

Comment: Scratch my last comment.  Moving the code to a module directly attached to the spreadsheet I'm working on fixes the problem, and it now loops through each worksheet.  Why does this not work when saved within my personal macro workbook?